# Android AVD Incompatibility

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, incompatibility, run-configuration

When I try and run an Android AVD, the emulator doesn't run my app. I've gone into run configurations, and gone to target device to set a preferred AVD to run.

Each AVD I select I get an error saying: 'Nexus 4' may be incompatible with your configuration(AVD vendor(Android Open Source Project) != AVD target (Google Inc.))

I'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In your project change SDK build target from **Google APIs (x.x)** to **Android x.x.x**

Comment: How do you change the SDK build target?

Comment: in android application-manifest file change the value of this property android:targetSdkVersion. In addition, your simulator should be the same version